# Error while installing APR on backtrack linux 5r3

Tags: apache, libtool, apr, backtrack-linux

When i am trying to install apache server it showed the following error on `./configure`

```
checking for APR... configure: WARNING: APR version 1.4.0 or later is required, found 1.3.8
configure: WARNING: skipped APR at apr-1-config, version not acceptable
no
configure: error: APR not found.  Please read the documentation
```

.

So i tried to upgrade to  apr-1.4.6.I downloaded the tarball and extracted it.
Also `make` got the following error

```
libtool: link: you must specify an output file
libtool: link: Try `libtool --help --mode=link' for more information.
make[1]: *** [libapr-.la] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/Desktop/apr'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

still i proceeded for `make install`

On `make install` i got the following error

```
libtool: link: you must specify an output file
libtool: link: Try `libtool --help --mode=link' for more information.
make: *** [libapr-.la] Error 1
```

Any help How to solve this out??
I need to `upgrade from apache 2.2.4 to apache 2.4.4.`
Any alternative suggestions are welcome

Comment: You've cut off all of the information required to figure out what's failing with your compile.  :)  You need to tell us at least the libtool command that make tried to run, and any other context before the error from make.

Comment: I'm not familiar with backtrack linux; doesn't it have any kind of package management?

Comment: ... In fact, it does -- `apt-get`. Also, out of curiosity: why are you trying to run a distribution specialized for penetration testing as a server or desktop system?

Comment: @Shadur yes it had package management....and to install a httpd apache linux system need APR preinstalled.

Comment: So use the package manager to install apache 2.4 and APR.